# How to install iwidgets without root access and set the enviornment

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user, csh, tcl

Recently, I want to run a script (PWgui) which requires Tcl (Itk). The manual suggests that I have to install iwidgets4 beforehand. I am using the university cluster and don't have any root privileges. My questions are:

1. How to install iwidgets4 without root access?
2. After the installation, how to set the environment so that Itk could be called whenever is needed? (The cluster uses .cshrc)